# Django sqlall <app> not returning anything

Tags: sql, django, models

Ran into a small problem today. Was easily fixed with a bit of research, but wanted to throw it up here in case anyone had something similar.

My app file layout was like so:

```
>cart
-->Models
----> __init__.py
----> cart.py
----> items.py
--> __init__.py
```

So I did not have a standard `models.py` file, obviously. I wanted to run `python manage.py sqlall cart` in order to see the sql code to insert it in my SQL Server database. The problem was, every time I ran that code, it returned nothing. What's the fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that makes sense, because it is looking for a `models.py` file and not finding one, only `Models` submodule.

You have to use [app_label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label) on each of the sub-model items. So both the `cart.py` and `items.py` files need their `Meta` tags edited to be have:

```
class Meta:
    app_label="cart"
```

This tells Django that this model belongs to that app, explicitly. As the Django Docs say,

> If a model exists outside of the standard models.py (for instance, if
>   the app’s models are in submodules of myapp.models), the model must
>   define which app it is part of

Then, the `sqlall <app>` command should work as you want it too.

Comment: This is probably *the* most annoying thing with Django.  Whenever you deviate from having a single models.py file the app_label is required AFAICT.  The output from the sql commands don't hint that models were found but not loaded which is quite frustrating.  Thanks for posting the issue and solution!